# Restaurando banco de dados sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Estou criando um ambiente de desenvolvimento. 
Fui no ambiente de produção abri o sql server management studio botão direito no banco tarefas > fazer backup 
Voltei no ambiente de desenvolvimento abri o sql server management studio
Tarefas > restaurar > Banco de dados

Nessa tela não estou conseguindo restaurar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em origem você seleciona dispositivos; clica nas reticencias e escolhe o arquivo

Comment: Você selecionou o banco de dados que deseja restaurar? Tem uma mensagem de erro informando exatamente o que está acontecendo...

Comment: @LINQ clico para escolher e não aparece nada, clico nas reticencias e não aparece o arquivo bak.

Comment: @Herick Cara, tem um botão gigante escrito **Add**. Não tem?